# Dataframe containing a list of values

Tags: r

```
Attribute             Time       Value
pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 12,51,34,17 
pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 84,28,17,10 
pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 11,43,28,15
pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 80,26,17,91 
pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 10,41,25,13 
pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 97,35,23,12
```

I am doing my internship in a company! They have data like this for doing KS test. Value column is an array of values but R reads it as character.  I want to calculate sum of all the Values when `Attribute` is `pmEulRlcUserPacketThp` and `Time` is `2013-04-30`. How can I do this?

`Attribute` contains various pm... and `Time` is monthly data from `30-4-2013` to `30-5-2013`. So I should have one vector for each `Attribute` and each date.
Kindly help me with this..!

It doesn't work with different vector lengths in rows

```
df = read.table(text="Attribute             Time       Value
    pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 12,51,34,17 
    pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 84,28,17,10 
    pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 11,43,28,15
    pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 80,26,17,91 
    pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 10,41,25,13 
    pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 97,35,23,12,13", 
                 header = TRUE, fill = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=F)
dfL <- concat.split.multiple(df, "Value", direction = "long")

"Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 6, 7"
```

This is the error I get! 
What can be done with the data containing vector of different lengths?

## For different dates:

```
df = read.table(text="Attribute Time Value
 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 12,51,34,17
 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-29 84,28,17,10
 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-28 11,43,28,15
 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-27 80,26,17,91
 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-26 10,41,25,13
 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-25 97,35,23,12",
                 header = TRUE, fill = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Now my data looks like this. I have done all concatenation steps- The data I have now is

```
> y
              Attribute       Time V1 V2 V3 V4
1 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 12 51 34 17
2 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-29 84 28 17 10
3 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-28 11 43 28 15
4 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-27 80 26 17 91
5 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-26 10 41 25 13
6 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-25 97 35 23 12
```

Now what I want is, aggregation of V1,V2,V3,V4 for two time periods- one being (27th to 30th and another being 25th-26th). I am using subsetting which is not feasible for a huge data n many elements.

```
> y1<-y[1:4,]
> y1
              Attribute       Time V1 V2 V3 V4
1 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 12 51 34 17
2 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-29 84 28 17 10
3 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-28 11 43 28 15
4 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-27 80 26 17 91

> y2<-y[-(1:4),]
> y2
              Attribute       Time V1 V2 V3 V4
5 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-26 10 41 25 13
6 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-25 97 35 23 12

> z1<-aggregate(V1 ~ Attribute, y1, sum)
> z1
              Attribute  V1
1 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 187
> z2<-aggregate(V1 ~ Attribute, y2, sum)
> z2
              Attribute  V1
1 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 107
```

This is jus for V1 for two different time intervals.This has to be done for other Values also(V2,V3,V4). This is time consuming. Is there any way to do selection of dates using aggregation ?

Comment: Aishwaryaa, sorry, but continuous edits to get us to do more of your work for you isn't really the way to approach using Stack Overflow. In this case, your most recent edit is ***very*** different from your original question. It would be better to roll-back to your earlier version and post your follow up as a new question, along with a clear indication of what you tried and what you're expecting as an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Your question has really changed a lot since it was originally asked, and that's generally not great SO behavior. However, I'm feeling generous...

This solution uses `concat.split.multiple` from "splitstackshape" and `aggregate` and `cut` from base R to get the solution that it seems you want:

Load "splitstackshape" and make sure it is at least version `1.2.0` (most recent at the time of posting this):

```
library(splitstackshape)
## Make sure you're running at least version 1.2.0
packageVersion("splitstackshape")
# [1] ‘1.2.0’
```

Here is your sample data:

```
df <- read.table(text="Attribute Time Value
 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 12,51,34,17
 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-29 84,28,17,10
 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-28 11,43,28,15
 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-27 80,26,17,91
 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-26 10,41,25,13
 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-25 97,35,23,12",
 header = TRUE, fill = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

First, split up the "Value" column.

```
y <- concat.split.multiple(df, "Value")
```

Next, create an "interval" column for the date ranges that you want to use.

```
y$interval <- cut(as.Date(y$Time), breaks=c(as.Date(
  c("2013-04-25", "2013-04-27", "2013-04-30"))), include.lowest=TRUE)
```

Finally, `aggregate` your data. The `. ~` notation lets you aggregate all the non-ID columns at once.

```
aggregate(. ~ Attribute + interval, y[-2], sum)
#               Attribute   interval Value_1 Value_2 Value_3 Value_4
# 1 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-25     107      76      48      25
# 2 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-27     187     148      96     133
```

---

FYI: *If you are using version 1.2.0, you should no longer get the error you mentioned in your post. That error was due to how `read.table` decides how many columns to create. It only reads the first 5 rows, and the example where you ran into problems had the longer row on the sixth row. I've implemented `count.fields` to overcome this problem. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.*

Comment: I *should* refuse to upvote any answer you give using this package until you rename it *shapeshifter*... :-) But I can't. +1

Comment: Thanks a lot! This package is pretty cool! My data is huge. I have started playing around with this! Will post if i find any difficulty!

Comment: @AnandaMahto Is there any option to get the resulting split vector in the original form? I mean, now I have the sum of all individual Values for each day and each attribute. I want the result in the form of the original vector. Is there any de.concatenate or something similar?

Comment: @AnandaMahto What I meant is that, I have aggregated for each attribute n time. According to the above data i ll have one sum for each Value (i.e Value_1 , Value_2, Value_3 and Value_4). Is there any possibility to put them back together as a vector in a column called Value. So that I ll have a dataframe of one row and 3 columns, with attribute being pm... time being 2013.04.30 and Value being a vector of all four values..(820, sum(value2),.. ,sum(value4))

Comment: @AnandaMahto Thanks a lot! The package is awesome! I just came to know u are the Author.. ! Thanks again. Btwn, Is it possible to handle vectors of different lengths also using this package..? Its easier in this case, all rows have equal length (Value) , what if its unequal data!

Comment: @AnandaMahto I have updated the question! I am not able to get the result. Hope you can help me with this!

Comment: @AishwaryaaViswanathan, I've updated my answer again. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is this getting close to what you want?

```
df = read.table(text="Attribute             Time       Value
  pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 12,51,34,17 
  pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 84,28,17,10 
  pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 11,43,28,15
  pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 80,26,17,91 
  pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 10,41,25,13 
  pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 97,35,23,12", 
                header = TRUE, fill = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=F)


values = data.frame(t(matrix(unlist(strsplit(df$Value, ',')), ncol = nrow(df))))
values = mapply(values, FUN = function(row){as.numeric(as.character(row))})
df = cbind(df[,1:2], values)

aggregate(df$X1, by=list(df$Attribute, df$Time), FUN=sum)
aggregate(df$X2, by=list(df$Attribute, df$Time), FUN=sum)
```

Comment: Why not just `aggregate(. ~ Attribute + Time, df, sum)` if you wanted each `x`, and `rowSums(aggregate(. ~ Attribute + Time, df, sum)[3:6])` if you wanted the overall sum?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I guess the package @AnandaMahto has mentioned is pretty cool. I am trying both anyways!

Comment: If you have big dataset its advisable to use `as.numeric(levels(factorobject))[factorobject` instead of `as.numeric(as.character(factorobject))` to coerce factors to character.

Comment: Is there any option to get the resulting split vector in the original form? I mean, now I have the sum of all individual Values for each day and each attribute. I want the result in the form of the original vector. Is there any de.concatenate or something similar?

Comment: `aggregated$newvector = paste(aggregated$X1, aggregated$X2, ..., sep=',')` should give you a new column in that format.